# When hosting on EC2, should I use FS to store files "locally" or s3fs to store files on my s3 service "indirectly"?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm hosting a node.js express application on EC2, and i'm using Amazon's S3 storage service.

Within my application, hosted on amazon, should I write the files locally (since the server is already running on aws) or should I still use the s3fs package to store the files on the S3 service as if I'm on a remote machine?

Thanks all!

Comment: Depends - S3 is probably cheaper, but if you're just caching temp files, use fs. What are you doing with the files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use s3fs. It's nice, but if you try to use it in production, it will be a nightmare. S3FS has to 'translate' any AWS errors into the very limited set that a filesystem can return. It also can't give you fine-grained control of retries, etc.

It's much better to write code to interact with S3. You will be able to get the full error from S3, you can decide what your retry policy is, etc.